# Ajax is not a function e-signature

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem when i try to click on the save button who call ajax. in order to save the signature of the canvas.

I'm using laravel 5.5 for the project.

On another project laravel 5.4 i use ajax with : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` with any problems;

I don't know maybe i have a conflict version of Jquery.

Hope someone could help me.

here my page :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.3.6/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>


    $(function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
        drawSignatureLine();
        $('button.save').click(function(){
            // window.open(signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png"));
            var canvas_img_data = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png");
            var img_data = canvas_img_data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            //ajax call to save image inside folder
            $.ajax({
                url: 'save/signature/composition/equipe',
                data: { img_data:img_data },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
        $('button.clear').click(function(){
            signaturePad.clear();
            drawSignatureLine();
        });
        function drawSignatureLine(){
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.lineWidth = .5;
            context.strokeStyle = '#333';
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 150);
            context.lineTo(500, 150);
            context.stroke();
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: "On another project" - with or without any problems?
What is JS error in network tab of browser inspector element?

Comment: Open up chrome inspect and go to console tab and male sure you don't have any javascript errors before you call ajax because in that case, the error doesn't allow jquery to be loaded.

Comment: I have any errors before ajax function when i remove it